# How to have a conditional for a custom attribute in serverless framework based on stage postfix

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have a custom attribute in my serverless.yml which value should be set based on the condition if the stage contains the postfix `-test`. This custom attribute contains a `ssm` path which is later resolved using `$ssm:...` for an environment variable.

My approach was something like the following (but I am not sure if the condition will work)

```
custom:
  MySqsParam:
    Fn::If:
      - IsTest
      - /somePath/${self:provider.stage}/A/arn
      - /somePath/${self:provider.stage}/B/arn

resources:
  Conditions:
    IsTest:
      Fn::Equals:
        - ${self:provider.stage}
        - ${Fn::Sub('${self:provider.stage}', '-test', '')}-test

provider:
  environment:
    MY_SQS_PARAM: ${ssm:${self:custom.MySqsParam}}
```

However when I want to deploy it I always receive the following error:

```
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.MY_SQS_PARAM": Non-string address argument in variable "ssm" source: [object Object]
```

It looks like the Conditional is not even resolved because when I try this:

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    IsTest:
      Fn::Equals:
        - ${self:provider.stage}
        - ${self:provider.stage}
```

Which should always be true I get the same error: